# Webcam streaming using gstreamer over UDP

Tags: gstreamer

Here is what I'm trying:

`gst-launch -v udpsrc port=1234 ! fakesink dump=1`

I test with:

`gst-launch -v audiotestsrc ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234`

And everything works fine, I can see the packages arriving from the `audiotestsrc`

Now lets test with the webcam source:

`gst-launch -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! queue ! videoscale method=1 ! "video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240" ! queue ! videorate ! "video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=(fraction)15/1" ! queue ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234`

And nothing happens, no package appears in the dump.

Here is a [logdump](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1f16) of what verbose shows in the server.

Does anyone have a clue on this?

Comment: Forgot to mention: replacing udpsink with autovideosink for example I can see the webcam just fine

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try these (You may have to install gstreamer-ugly plugins for this one)

**UDP streaming from Webcam (stream over the network)**

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480' !  x264enc pass=qual quantizer=20 tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234
```

**UDP Streaming received from webcam (receive over the network)**

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=1234 ! "application/x-rtp, payload=127" ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

**Update**

To determine the payload at the streaming end simply use verbose option with `gst-launch -v ...`

Comment: It is a good idea to include a queue between encoding and streaming. Allows for better timing and less jittery playback.

Comment: @AtillaFiliz I tend to use 'queue' when working with 'tee' although your point may be valid in this case.

Comment: I did some experiments of my own. I used some specialized hardware on the encoder side, and adding a queue did not make any difference. However, playback quality improved a lot when I added a queue between rtpdepay and ffdec.

Comment: A queue element decouples the flow by sending on data in another thread. See http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-queue.html and http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/wiki/FAQ#head-9f14f8ce765b3d24c91660db5f02e3345da98a35

Answer (score 4):

Maybe packets are too large for udp? They are limited to 64K. Try resizing frames to really small size to check if this is the reason. If so, you may be interested in some compression and payloaders/depayloaders (`gst-inspect | grep pay`).

Answer (score -1):

gstreamer1-1.16.0-1.fc30

gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/.../.../.../sample-mp4-file.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! queue ! rtph264pay **config-interval=10** pt=96 ! udpsink port=8888 host=127.0.0.1

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP_audio_video_profile

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit?