# How to use gstreamer command show on my website?

Tags: html, real-time, webcam, gstreamer

**UDP streaming from Webcam (stream over the network)**                                        gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480' ! x264enc pass=qual quantizer=20 tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234

**UDP Streaming received from webcam (receive over the network)**                                  gst-launch udpsrc port=1234 ! "application/x-rtp, payload=127" ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false

I got this command from "enthusiasticgeek"  [Webcam streaming using gstreamer over UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669240/webcam-streaming-using-gstreamer-over-udp)

**My problem is?**

I want to use these command above to show real-time streaming on my website.How could I do? Do you have any Idea , any solution or the example just like html code or something ?

Thank you for help =)

Answer (score 0):

You need a streaming server to do so, not just some pipelines.

One server you could use is [Flumotion](http://www.flumotion.net)

Comment: Thank you so much.I will try Flumotion for my streaming server.If I can't do it or I got a problem I will ask you again later.thank you again =)