# Network streaming using Gstreamer

Tags: udp, streaming, gstreamer

I tried the following basic **pipelines to play** audio over a network:

```
Server:
gst-launch-0.10 -v audiotestsrc ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234
Client:
gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc port=1234 ! fakesink dump=1
```

But I get **no output**, although the pipeline gets set to **PLAYING state**.

I looked at other questions such as this one : [Webcam streaming using gstreamer over UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669240/webcam-streaming-using-gstreamer-over-udp)
Although it's the same pipeline there too, it doesn't work for me.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me. The server command line sets pipeline to PLAYING and just sits there, presumably sending audio noise into the UDP ether. The client command line spews hex data from the received buffers. What are you seeing that differs from this?

Comment: @MultimediaMike I get no data dumped at all. I hacked at it a bit, and i got it working if i add the "multicast-group" of udpsrc to localhost. But i have no idea why. And, even that doesnt work if i change the host to something other than localhost...if it helps, i'm connected to a private network with a firewall. does that matter?

Comment: It might be a firewall related issue (meaning a firewall software on your local PC). What OS are you using? i assume some sort of linux. Check which iptables rules are configured

Comment: I'm using windows 7..

Comment: I had success running on Linux. I agree with mreithub that there might be a firewall issue on Windows. Look for "Windows Firewall and Advanced Security" and see if there's anything in there (like temporarily disabling it) that might help in this proof of concept.

Comment: This has taken ages, but I finally got around to running this on linux. And it worked. The problem in windows was my office proxy server controlling the traffic. Thanks guys.