# GStreamer udpsink (Windows)

Tags: gstreamer

Simplest possible gstreamer networking test, from a batch file:

```
gst-launch-0.10 audiotestsrc ! udpsink host=192.168.1.100 port=23000
```

A quick glance with Wireshark reveals that no packets are being sent (a "full" test with transmitter and receiver also shows no network communications happening).

Windows 7, with firewall turned off.  Same result in Windows XP.

Comment: Are you on a proxy network of any kind? refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492591/network-streaming-using-gstreamer

Comment: You should use gstreamer 1.x. 0.10 is no longer maintained and has many known problems, including network related problems on Windows. You can find new binaries at: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.4.3/

Answer (score 2):

see bug report https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=706588
you should use new version gstreamer