# Gstreamer - Stream to be read to multiple clients

Tags: gstreamer

I have a video stream which is encoded in h264 (and it has to be in h264). I want to be able to read my stream from n clients. I know we can use tee to split our pipline. I have also seen the v4l2sink which allows me to turn the stream into a video device, but it wont work with h264 streams. Is there any way I can take a stream and have it be read by multiple clients? kind of like how /dev/video0 (webcam) but can be opened by multiple clients.

Current pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc port=5001 ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink t. ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with coding, only streaming.

Comment: You can try to use udp port for sharing.

Comment: @LennartManfred yes, I can just use tee and use a bunch of different ports. Any other way I am missing?

Comment: This is udp port usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669240/webcam-streaming-using-gstreamer-over-udp